# Making a website commenting system

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, comments

Me and a friend are trying to make a commenting system for our website, We have a somewhat simple bit of code to insert values into a mysql database to then later be read and displayed as comments, however the data is not sending correctly to the table at the moment. We are both fairly new to ajax, php and mysql so it may be just a stupid mistake! :P

The html:

```
<form id="postComment" action="Comments.js"  method="post"> 
<input type="email" name="email" onchange="checkEmail();" id="email" /> </br>
<div id ="emailerror">
<p id="emailerror"> </p>
</div> </br>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" /> </br>
<input type="text" name="content" id="content" /> </br>
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="commentUpload();" />



</form>
```

The Javascript file:

```
function commentUpload() //uploads comment to sQl table
{
var email = document.getElementById("email").value //gets the user's email
var username = document.getElementById("username").value //gets the user's username
var content = document.getElementById("content").value //gets the comment content
// var articleName = document.getElementById("articleName") gets the article name

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","commentUpload.php?email=" + email + "&username=" +username +    "&content="+content,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
```

And the php:

```
<?php 

$email=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
$username=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']);
$content=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['content']);


$query="INSERT INTO Comments
VALUES (1, email, username, content)";


mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
?>
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: there are a lot of errors on your code. You must not use your javascript file as a form action. Also you must not use duplicate `ids` -> `emailerror`. For your ajax Request i would recommend you to use jQuery. And you don't fill you mySQL query qith your variable date.

Comment: You give a bunch of code, and you say that "the data is not sending correctly to the table at the moment". I think a more accurate presentation of what is actually happening will make people more likely to be able (and willing) to help you. For example, does nothing get in to the database now? Do you have any error messages? If something is inserted, how is it wrong?

Comment: jQuery AJAX simplifies the JavaScript part; see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Also, if you're serious about coding this yourselves, read about SQL injection (and why you should NEVER use data that comes from a user in ANY SQL without sanitizing it first). Doing it the way you've tried to do it would allow an attacker to (easily) break your database, and possibly read data from your database you didn't intend to be available (depending on your PHP settings).

Comment: Is that the exact PHP code? If so you've not created a database connection (`mysql_connect`), and you're also not adding your variables correctly into the SQL string. Furthermore, you shouldn't trigger `commentUpload()` from the click handler; use `onsubmit="commentUpload();return false;"` on the form element instead.

Comment: Ok well it looks like we need to do some serious learning before getting stuck into this... can anyone point us in the right direction? Preferably websites as apposed to books...

Comment: @Thor84no I have found out that mysql_real_escape_string prevents sql attacks... Is this true for every type of attack, or do I need to do more to prevent them?

Comment: @simonthumper That's a good start, but I'd recommend using prepared statements as well. Prepared statements are statements where you use a placeholder (typically ?'s or named parameters like ":name"), then assign variables to it. Not only does this allow your driver to escape certain things for you, but it also allows it to do the query plan up-front the first time and re-use the same query plan every time you run the query (better performance).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So this may be me, but I would suggest you don't use any javascript when adding or uploading the comments; ajax can provide some wonderfully powerful code, but it's probably be better to use it when querying from the database on the clientside as opposed to inserting to the database on the serverside!

You HTML code should instead jump directly to the PHP, as opposed to being transitioned through the AJAX as you had previously programmed. And instead of using some javascript to change between $_POST and $_GET, you can simply change the method in the HTML.

```
<form id="postComment" action="comments.php" method="get">
```

Next, you must be sure to include a connection to your database. [w3Schools has a nice tutorial on establishing connections](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp). At the same time, you must also be sure to concatenate your parameters that you got from the $_GET into the query string using periods.

```
<?php 

    $email =mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']);
    $content = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['content']);

    $connect = mysql_connect("server","name","password");
    if (!$con) {die('Unable to connect..!!';}
    mysql_select_db("database", $connect);

    $query = "insert into Comments values (1,'" . $email 
    ."', '" . $username . "', '". $content . "')";

    mysql_query($query);
    mysql_close();

?>
```

I hope that helped! Best of luck with the rest of the website!

Comment: Thanks for the help! that makes things a lot easier. Rest of the websites already done as a matter of fact ;) This is the last thing we're adding in

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, you're never inserting the values you want into your query. This line of code:

```
$query="INSERT INTO Comments VALUES (1, email, username, content)";
```

At some point it needs to receive the variables you've collected before, like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Comments VALUES (1, %s, %s, %s)";
$query = sprintf($query, $email, $username, $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your $query in php is whrong. You need to insert the variables into it. Also if the first

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Comments VALUES (1, '" . $email ."', 
'" . $username . "', '". $content . "')";
```

Also don't forget that if you insert a string into SQL you'll need to add '   ' around the value, like I did in my example.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to run go "localhost/commentUpload.php" ? you need to see some errors. If so you should fix your sql code. As first answer stated. You should use auto_increment for id.